# How to convert string pic URL to image and display in image tag .?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have like this kind of pic URL

```
C:\inetpub\MaujApp\OMSAPI\ManualRecevingImages\WhatsApp Image 2021-03-24 at 12.07.41 PM.jpeg
```

and I want to convert a original image and display a user by using jQuery.
like this by using jQuery and C#
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepend`

Below will prepend an `<img>` tag inside `<div>`

```js
const imgUrl = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/f6/fb/51f6fb256629fc755b8870c801092942.png"

$('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="'+imgUrl+'" />')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="theDiv">
</div>
```